# SystemC sc_uint from String Object

Tags: c++, systemc

I've started using `SystemC` recently and wanted to write a simple program that reads numbers from a file in the `SystemC` string format and converts them into `sc_uint` types. Somehow the simple program always fails during the conversion

The program:

```
#include <systemc.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int sc_main( int argc, char *argv[] ){
    ifstream in_file;
    std::string line;
    char *buffer;

    in_file.open( "ex3_2.dat", ios::in );

    while( getline( in_file, line ) ){
        sc_uint<29> x = line.c_str();
    }

    return( 0 );
}
```

The ex3_2.dat file

```
0x1234\n
```

The output

> **Error: (E403) conversion failed: character string is empty**

I do not get why the conversion breaks.

> c_str() should return a const char*.

Printing the String to cout shows the right value for line.

Static assignments like "0x1234" do work.
Does somebody have an idea?

Comment: Have you tried printing the string? Is it what you expected?

Comment: Yes. Printing the string shows exactly what I expected "0x1234"

Comment: Is there any other context around the error? It's a runtime exception rather than a compile error, right?

Comment: No compilation works without problem. Execution starts with the normal SystemC header followed by the error.

Answer (score 0):

The following code

```
#include <systemc.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

#include <iostream>

int sc_main( int argc, char *argv[] ){

    std::ifstream in_file;
    std::string line;

    in_file.open( "ex3_2.dat", ios::in );

    while( getline( in_file, line ) ){
        sc_uint<29> x = line.c_str();
       std::cout << "0x" << std::hex << x << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

with the ex3_2.dat file

```
0x1234
5
6
7
8
```

compiled with the following

```
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -o main.o main.cpp -lsystemc
```

produces

```
0x00001234
0x00000005
0x00000006
0x00000007
0x00000008
```

g++ --version = g++ (GCC) 7.1.0

No compiler warnings or errors are emitted. The conclusion being that the code itself is fine. Perhaps look for the errors elsewhere, what std library versions are linked etc. Hidden characters in the file? ASCII vs UTF-8? Too many possibilities to narrow it down from here.